# FTSE 350 sector index historical data

Tags: equities, data, market-data, historical-data

Does anyone know where I can find (at least 10 years worth of) end of day historical `(op, hi, lo, cl)` data for the FTSE 350 Sector Indices?.

I need the data for private/personal research so I'm looking for either a free, or inexpensive source.